# Structure d'une proposition

Tags: syntaxe

La phrase susmentionnée faite partie d'une QCM :

> Un kilogramme de carbone nécessite 4/3 kilogrammes d’oxygène et produit
>   combien de kilogrammes de monoxyde de carbone?

A. ... B. ... etc.

Je me demande si cette question a de bonne syntaxe et si est compréhensible. Faut-il que je modifie la deuxième phrase ? E.g.,

> ...et combien de kilogrammes de...produit-il ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Du point de vue de la structure de la phrase, la seconde proposition serait plus correcte. Pour rendre la question encore plus lisible, je la séparerais en deux parties : les données, et la question :

> Un kilogramme de carbone nécessite 4/3 kilogrammes d’oxygène.
>   Combien de kilogrammes de monoxyde de carbone produit-il ?

Je ne dirais pas non plus qu'un kg de carbone 'nécessite' une certaine quantité d'oxygène : c'est pour *une réaction particulière* que cette quantité sera nécessaire. On dira plutôt que "un kg de carbone réagit avec n kg d'oxygène".

Du point de vue de la chimie, je ne poserais pas cette question. Elle semble sous-entendre que tout le carbone va réagir avec l'oxygène selon la réaction :

> 2 C + O2 -> 2 CO

ce qui ne s'observera jamais en réalité. La combustion du carbone produit essentiellement du CO2, comme la plupart des étudiants devraient le supposer, et ne produira jamais 100% de CO (cf. équilibre de Boudouard).

Juste une petite remarque annexe : QCM (Questionnaire à Choix Multiples) est masculin.

Answer (score 2):

En soit, la syntaxe est bonne et compréhensible. Néanmoins, la question porte sur la production de monoxyde de carbone, je mettrais donc la question en premier:

> Combien de kilogrammes de monoxyde de carbone sont produit par 1 kg de
>   carbone et 4/3 de kg d'oxygène.

Note à part, on écrit rarement kilogramme en entier mais plutôt kg et les divisions sont très peu utilisées: on utilise plutôt 1.333 kg au lieu de 4/3 kg.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a une affirmation et une question, or le "et" devrait relier des groupes équivalent. Soit vous séparez les deux

> Un kilogramme de carbone nécessite 4/3 kilogrammes d’oxygène pour brûler. Combien de kilogrammes de monoxyde de carbone cette réaction produit-elle?

Soit vous introduisez l'affirmation dans un subordonnée

> Sachant/En supposant que la combustion d'un kilogramme de carbone nécessite 4/3 kilogrammes d'oxygène, combien de kilogrammes de monoxyde de carbone cette réaction produit-elle?

EDIT: Je n'ai considéré que la syntaxe